# Using DEFAULT value in condional statements and SET

Tags: sql, default-value, h2

There is something wrong with DEFAULT keyword handling

Example:

```
 CREATE TABLE BAR(c1 int null,c2 int default 1 not null)
```

Executing SQL like this:

```
 INSERT INTO BAR SET c1 = 1, c2 = COALESCE(null,DEFAULT)
```

**Results in:
Column "DEFAULT" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO BAR SET c1 = 1, c2 = COALESCE(null,DEFAULT) [42122-161]
42S22/42122**

At the same time:

```
INSERT INTO BAR (c1,c2) values (1,  DEFAULT)
```

Ok!

But,

```
 INSERT INTO BAR SET c1 = 1, c2  = DEFAULT
```

**Result:
NULL not allowed for column "C2"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO BAR SET c1 = 1, c2  = DEFAULT [23502-161] 23502/23502**

I think it is a bug. If it is not, is any way to specify use of
default value exists?

H2 1.3.161 (2011-10-28)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term DEFAULT isn't a pseudo-column or an expression that can be used in a formula. DEFAULT is used *instead* of an expression. I tried MySQL and it works in the same way as H2.

```
drop table foo cascade;
CREATE TABLE FOO(c1 int null,c2 int default 1 not null);
INSERT INTO FOO SET c1 = 1, c2 = default; -- works
INSERT INTO FOO SET c1 = 1, c2 = default * 2; -- doesn't work
```

What you probably want is use a parameterized statement (right?) where NULL is converted to default. H2 does support this, but it's not fully documented. You can use:

```
drop table foo cascade;
CREATE TABLE FOO(c1 int null,c2 int default 1 not null null_to_default);
INSERT INTO FOO SET c1 = 1, c2 = null;
```

Comment: INSERT INTO BAR SET c1 = 1, c2  = DEFAULT; -- not works in H2

Comment: There is DEFAULT(column_name) command in MySQL:

    INSERT INTO BAR SET c1 = 1, c2  = coalesce(null,DEFAULT(c2));

Can you add support for it?

Comment: `INSERT INTO BAR SET c1 = 1, c2 = DEFAULT` does work for me. If it doesn't work for you, please post the complete code (including create table statement and so on). `DEFAULT(c2)` is not planned currently.